# How can I save the transaction log about rest CRUD API?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.2.4. and made some rest crud services using @RestController. If I executed crud operation and return 200 to the client well.  And If it is guaranteed, I want to save the log in my transaction table. How can I add this logic? It have to be general and common where every controllers can use.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to log?

If you want the access log, you can add these to the application.properties.

`server.tomcat.access-log-pattern= # log pattern of the access log
server.tomcat.access-log-enabled=false # is access logging enabled`

If you want to log something special, you can use the AOP to log whatever you want like this:

http://tianmaying.com/snippet/8ab3eda84ce67d14014cebb0e1780239